# not able to use while() always true?

Tags: c, while-loop

Basically I am trying to find the speed and how far can my CPU can calculate in C.

here is what I am trying to do;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 100;
    while(1==1){
        i *= i;
        printf("[i] : %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but with above code, the program never compile/start and get stuck at the beginning, it even make the program say **Not Responding**.

I am using code::block, and never see any output on the console.

All replies are much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `int i` to `volatile int i`. IIRC a while true loop on non-volatile memory is safe to be removed by the compiler.

Comment: Highly related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387181/mcu-programming-c-o2-optimization-breaks-while-loop

Comment: It "works" here, but since it's inherently broken it's hard to define what that means, but there is output. https://ideone.com/jc7LIe

Comment: Your program isn't responding because it is busy in your endless loop. Your program can not be used to find any speed of any sorts (e.g. printing output is many orders of magnitude slower than doing a simple multiplication), and multiplication like that will overflow and cause undefined behavior. You should rather tell us what kind of environment you are running this in, and whether you see any output at all, either in a console window or in the output window of your IDE if you are using one, and what you really want to achieve with your program.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: @jabberwocky, it's windows 7x64, Code::Blocks, but it also does't work at `onlinegdb.com`

Comment: BTW you don't need the `1==1` to get a "true" value, you can just use `1` on its own as anything except 0 is considered "true"

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf look at my updated answer and let us know if the modifed version of your programs works better.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, that works but why am I getting the same output while using `int64_t i = 100` or `long long int` ?

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf because `int64_t` and `long long int` is the same thing on your platform.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, sorry for misunderstanding, I meant, `int` and `long long int` have the same output

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf because the format specifier for `long long int` is `%lld` and not `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works more or less as expected:

The output might be something like this: (// are my comments and not actually partof the output)

```
[i] : 10000             // 100 * 100
[i] : 100000000         // 10000 * 10000
[i] : 1874919424        // 100000000 * 100000000 (int overflow)
[i] : 0                 // 1874919424 * 1874919424 (int overflow resulting in 0)
[i] : 0                 // from now on you only get 0, because 0 * 0 = 0
[i] : 0
[i] : 0
[i] : 0
[i] : 0
[i] : 0
```

`int` overflow gives undefined behaviour and the result on your platform may be different.

Try this slightly modified version of your program, it performs only 10 loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i = 100;
  for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
  {
    i *= i;
    printf("[i] : %d\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```